# Get return value from forEach loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

```
result = input .every(function(value){
                if(value > 3)
                  return value;
            });
```

I want to catch return value and output should be like [4,5,6].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `every` returns `true/false` based on the condition you apply. In your case you are looking for `filter` as it will `return` the results for conditions which are true

```js
var input = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

result = input.filter(value => value > 3);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use filter or map instead.
As the above answers said, forEach does not return any value. (Instead its applying his magic on the object.) while Map & filter will bring you a new upgraded value.